# CodeIgniter .htaccess rewrite not working on Live Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a little problem with Code Igniter project, I have a .htaccess file to rewrite the index.php. It works great if I put my projects on Local Server. I am using WAMP Server. But now I have uploaded it on Live Server for example (godaddy,00webhost). And it is showing error :
404 Page Not Found.The page you requested was not found.

My .htaccess is here :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /directory_name/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favico​​n\.ico)   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and my config.php setting is here:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/directory/' ;
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I have tried many solutions on web but not enough lucky to find one who helps me. I am stuck since 3 days. Anyone Help me.

Comment: Check if, mod_rewrite module is enabled on live server.

Comment: Check if they are using Apache at all?

Comment: @Ravneet is this possible to check mod_rewrite module on live server?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 00webhost is using linux server.

Comment: That doesn't mean Apache. It could be Nginx or any other web server which doesn't use .htaccess files. Create an extra file under "public" containing only the code `<?php phpinfo();` then surf to that file: `http://your-domain.com/thefile.php` and see what it says about the server.

Comment: You can ask about server details, by dropping them email. phpinfo(), can be used to see the modules.

Comment: What version of CI you using? Check your file and class names make sure first letter is upper case on class and file name only on codeigniter 3 Also maybe try base url like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://directory.example.com/'`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i am using CI 2.2.6

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I found this have a look http://php0713061.herobo.com/address.php

Comment: Godady is using Apache by default

Comment: Is that the actuall server? Your site is hosted in the`public_html` and that folder only contains `address.php` and `default.php`.

Comment: Are you trying to host the site in a subfolder? Like `ci_foam`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes... my actuall site in inside ci_foam.. all Code Igniter folders.... and .htaccess file as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My Structure is Like this :

public_html
ci_foam
applicaiton
system
index.php
.htaccess

Comment: Did you copy that htaccess file from somewhere? change the RewriteBase /directory_name/ to RewriteBase /, you usually only need that on local

Comment: @Hedeshy but I have same problem at go daddy as well.. Even I upload my site without any sub directory.

Comment: @Hedeshy If  I changed RewriteBase /directory_name/ to RewriteBase / it shows me 500 internal error

Comment: I will suggest you to check the casing of the URL's because in windows uppercase and lowercase are treated to be same whereas they are different in linux. So double check your letters casing.

Comment: I have made all of my Controller names in Capital Letters.@HarshitChaudhary

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to host the website in a subfolder, make sure you enter the correct info in your htaccess and config:

Change `RewriteBase /directory_name/`in htaccess to `RewriteBase /ci_foam/`

Change `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/directory/'` in your config to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://php0713061.herobo.com/ci_foam/'`

You always need to make sure these values matches your current server setup.

Comment: I think @magnus answer is correct. just remove / after RewriteBase /ci_foam. it might work.